# How to check if a string is an int

Tags: java, user-interface

Ok guys, so I basically made a GUI Java program, a basic one. Just adds/subs/divides orr multiplies numbers that are in the textfields, nothing big as I have only started learning Java. It works but there are some bugs, such as when you execute it and if you click on one of the radiobutton without entering a number in the textfields then the programme will not work. How can I check whether the user entered an integer whenenver the user clicks on the radiobuttons?
Heres the code:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class GUI extends JFrame{

    Button button1;
    TextField num1;
    TextField num2;
    JRadioButton add,sub,mul,div;
    boolean isnumber = false;


    int x, y, sum;

    public static void main(String[] args){


        new GUI();

    }

    public GUI(){

        thehandler handle = new thehandler();

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setSize(800, 70);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setTitle("Calc");
        this.add(panel);



        button1 = new Button("Calculate");
        button1.addActionListener(handle);
        panel.add(button1);

        num1 = new TextField("Enter a number here");
        num1.addActionListener(handle);
        num2 = new TextField("Enter a number here");
        num2.addActionListener(handle);
        panel.add(num1);
        panel.add(num2);

        add = new JRadioButton("Add");
        add.addActionListener(handle);
        sub = new JRadioButton("Subtract");
        sub.addActionListener(handle);
        mul = new JRadioButton("Multiply");
        mul.addActionListener(handle);
        div = new JRadioButton("Divide");
        div.addActionListener(handle);

        ButtonGroup operation = new ButtonGroup();
        operation.add(add);
        operation.add(sub);
        operation.add(div);
        operation.add(mul);

        panel.add(add);
        panel.add(sub);
        panel.add(mul);
        panel.add(div);




    }

    private class thehandler implements ActionListener{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


            if(e.getSource() == add){
                sum = x + y;
                x = Integer.parseInt(num1.getText());
                y = Integer.parseInt(num2.getText());           
            }
            if(e.getSource() == sub){
                sum = x - y;
                x = Integer.parseInt(num1.getText());
                y = Integer.parseInt(num2.getText());
            }
            if(e.getSource() == mul){
                sum = x * y;
                x = Integer.parseInt(num1.getText());
                y = Integer.parseInt(num2.getText());
            }
            if(e.getSource() == div){
                sum = x/y;
                x = Integer.parseInt(num1.getText());
                y = Integer.parseInt(num2.getText());
            }
            if(e.getSource() == button1){

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The sum of the desired calculation is... " + sum);
            }

        }

    }



}
```

Comment: Put a try-catch around it and catch the `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a String is numeric in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102891/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-numeric-in-java)

Answer (score 4):

It depends what you mean by integer, but if you just want to check if string contains only digits and optionally `-` at start you can check it using regex like

```
yourString.matches("-?\\d+");
```

Note that this will not check range of number.

Comment: @Kuchi well, regex engine is not so light either but it is definitely easier to use than catching exception.

Answer (score 3):

Simply do:

```
String text = num1.getText();
try {
   Integer x = Integer.parseInt(text);
} catch (NumberFormatException) {
   System.out.println(text + " cannot be converted to integer");
}
```

If the String can't be parsed to `Integer`, a `NumberFormatException` will be thrown.

Comment: NumberFormatException requires an identifier, but other than that this code worked well for me!

Answer (score 1):

You should check, if the TextField is empty, and you should add some error handling to the integer parsing, like:

```
try {
    x = Integer.parseInt(num1.getText())>
catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
    //error handling
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert to `char[]` using `toCharArray()`

Then loop through and check if each character `isDigit()`

edit*
As others have said, catching exceptions is a much better way of handling this issue

Answer (score 0):

When `Integer.parseInt(...)` is given something it cannot parse, it throws a `NumberFormatException`. You should wrap your `parseInt(...)` calls in a try/catch block and handle the situation appropriately:

```
try {
    x = Integer.parseInt(num1.getText());
} catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    // do something about broken data
}
```

It woul dbe convenient to use a seperate method to do all the parsing and handlng to reduce the amount of code duplication

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function like this:

```
boolean isInt(String str) {
     for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
         char c = str.charAt(i);
         if (!Character.isDigit(c)) {
            return false;
         }
     }
     return true;
}
```

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit%28char%29